# Jaspersoft - Dynamic Reports Custom Font "Font is not available to the JVM"

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I currently use dynamic reports framework, which is a part of jasper soft reports, their official website is inactive for some reason, and all links to their documentation is unavailable.
To the point, I am facing a problem when trying to use a custom font in my java desktop application. I remember in the old documentation I had to put two files in the class path, a fonts.xml and a jasperreports_extensions.properties.

I have added these files to the class path with propper values, yet whenever I try to run the report I get tat "MyFont" is not available to the JVM.

propeties file content:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory

net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.drfonts=fonts.xml
```

fonts.xml content:

```
<fontFamilies>
<fontFamily name="MyFont">
    <normal>permitsapp/fonts/arial/arial.ttf</normal>
    <bold>permitsapp/fonts/arial/arialbd.ttf</bold>
    <italic>permitsapp/fonts/arial/ariali.ttf</italic>
    <boldItalic>permitsapp/fonts/arial/arialbi.ttf</boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
    <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
</fontFamily>
```

I tried looking all over the internet I found no help, if any is provided I'd be thankful!.

Comment: Are you using font extensions? Do you have a jar with font?

Comment: By font extensions you mean adding the properties file in my classpath? As you can see the extensions factory library exists in my classpath along with the properties file, and I have the font files in a local package in the same project.